# How to set logo on the center of qrcode tcpdf from html response PHP?

Tags: php, html, pdf, qr-code, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF library to generate pdf file using PHP. They also have feature to create qrcode.

This is my syntax

```
$style = array(
    'border' => 0,
    'vpadding' => 'auto',
    'hpadding' => 'auto',
    'fgcolor' => array(0, 0, 0),
    'bgcolor' => false, //array(255,255,255)
    'module_width' => 1, // width of a single module in points
    'module_height' => 1 // height of a single module in points
 );

$this->cetak->AddPage('P', 'A4');
$this->cetak->write2DBarcode("aaaaa", 'QRCODE,L', 155, $this->cetak->getY(), 30, 30, $style);
$this->cetak->Output('PKKPR.pdf', 'I');
die;
```

This is the output.

[image]

For html output qrcode, i am using this code.

```
    $barcodeobj = new TCPDF2DBarcode('http://www.tcpdf.org', 'QRCODE,H');
    print_r($barcodeobj->getBarcodeHTML(3, 3, 'black'));
    die;
```

This is the output.

[image]

How to make the logo inside the middle of qrcode? I tried to search for documentation but couldn't find about that. Is it even possible to set logo on the center of the qrcode ?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "logo inside the middle of qrcode"? I might be wrong here but a qrcode is simply a complex barcode. And if that's the case altering the middle will alter the data contained.

Comment: The OP is referring to this example http://en.qrcode-pro.com/qr-code-whb0/

Comment: @Prof yess just like that

Comment: You can actually add a logo just on top of it. A QR code is structured in way that it can work with missing information and I think there is also an option of how much redundancy you want. So basically even so you hide data, it will still work.

Comment: @butterbrot that's correct, there is an error correction level that you can change to increase / decrease the scan speed and distance but at the cost of generation time. You would slightly degrade scan speed / distance when adding a logo but then you can increase the generation time for higher quality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may stand corrected here, but I don't think the TCPDF barcode API can embed logos into QR codes. I recommend using the [endroid/qr-code](https://github.com/endroid/qr-code) library.

Build your QR code as per the examples, then embed the result into your PDF using a base 64 encoded data URI, something like this

```
use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode;

// Compile your QR code
$qr = QrCode::create('Data');

// Render to data URI
$data = $qr->getDataUri();

// Add to PDF page (WriteHTML example)
$pdf->writeHTML("<img src=\"$data\" width=\"200\" height=\"200\">");
```

Comment: I know i kinda late, but thanks for your answer, i follow your advice and made some helper to generate qrcode and parse it into my html!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the GD library (which it looks like you do), roll your own logo/qr combo using [getBarcodePNGData()](https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/TCPDF/classes-TCPDF2DBarcode/#method_%getBarcodePNGData), and applying your logo on top of it using [imagecopymerge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php)

```
$barcodeObj = new TCPDF2DBarcode('http://www.tcpdf.org', 'QRCODE,H');
$qrCode = $barcodeObj->getBarcodePNGData(3, 3, 'black');
$logo = imagecreatefrompng('logo.png');

//center in qr code
$logoX =  imagesx($qrCode)/2 - imagesx($logo)/2;
$logoY =  imagesy($qrCode)/2 - imagesy($logo)/2;

imagecopymerge($qrCode, $logo, 0, 0, $logoX, $logoY, imagesx($qrCode), imagesy($qrCode), 75);

imagepng($qrCode, null, 100); // this will stream the image out directly
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `endroid/qr-code` library as "Prof" suggest above you can also use `$pdf->Image` from data stream:

```
// Render to data as string  
$data = $qr->getString();

// The '@' character is used to indicate that follows an image data stream and not an image file name  
$pdf->Image('@'.$data);
```